# Use powershell to send an email in outlook without locking up if Outlook is already running

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have the following program:

```
Function Email{
  param ($to, $Subject, $Body, $Attachment)

    if($process=(get-process 'outlook'))
    {
      kill($process)
      Stop-Process $process -Force
      #$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
      #$namespace.Logon("outlook")
    }

    $Outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application
    $session = $outlook.Session
    $session.Logon("Outlook")

    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

    foreach ($person in $to){
      $Mail.Recipients.add($person)
    }

    $Mail.Subject = $Subject
    $Mail.Body = $Body
    $Mail.Attachments.Add($Attachment)
    $Mail.Send()
}
```

When tested in ISE and in batch, it functions as expected. However, when used in another powershell script, it randomly causes the script to hang up and I cannot open outlook manually due to an error about multiple instances.

How can I re-write this to properly account for an instance of outlook running (or at least so that it doesn't cause a script that uses it to hang up)?

Update: I have also tried it as:

```
Function Email{
    param ($to, $Subject, $Body, $Attachment)

    $Creds = Import-CliXml c:\localdata\cred.clixml
    $username= myemail
    Send-MailMessage -To $to -subject $Subject -body $Body -Attachment $Attachment -UseSsl -Port 587 -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -From $username -Credential $creds
}
```

and I cannot get past the "cannot connect to remote server" error

Running telnet smtp.office365.com 587 or telnet smtp.office365.com 25 doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: To diagnose and properly handle errors you can use try..catch statements so that the script does not just fail and stop whenever there is an error. Use the automatic `$error` variable and output to a text file in the catch statement to get the errors. In my experience working with MS Office COM objects can be very unreliable. Have you looked into sending the email using other methods, like `Send-MailMessage` ?

Comment: @robliv please see update

Comment: Are you working on a corporate network? Home office? Is there an antivirus installed on your computer?

Comment: @vonPryz on a corporate network protected by McAfee

Comment: Then it's possible McAfee blocks unauthorized SMTP connections. This is a common configuration that prevents botnets from using your workstation to send spam or worse. At this point, contact your IT department and work with them to get a solution.

Comment: vonPryz is right, there could be a security policy restricting you. Or there could be an issue with credentials. Try using private network, like your phone hotspot for internet and try sending the email again. As for credentials using the clixml is an interesting solution I have never used, you can try just running it without it and using it like `-credential (get-credential)` then a pop up will appear and just enter the user and pw yourself.If that works then make a PS credential object and pass that as parameter for `-credential`

Comment: The stored credentials must be created by the user that runs the service.(I think that's what you are trying to do, liikig at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314277/9898643))

Comment: I already created the credentials and ran it just with get-credential

Comment: It has the same behavior with get-credential